# Passing a nullable local variable to a where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL function:

```
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_BOOK_CODE_BY_AUTHOR_ID] 
(
    @AUTHOR_ID int
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @MOT_N_ID int, 
        @SCO_N_ID int,

        @BOOK_CODE varchar(50);


        select 

        @MOT_N_ID = AUT.MOT_N_ID,

        @SCO_N_ID = AUT.SCO_N_ID


        from AUTHOR AUT
        where AUT.AUT_ID = @AUTHOR_ID

    SELECT
        @BOOK_CODE = (
                select BOO.BOO_CH_CODE
                from BOOK BOO
                where
                and BOO.MOT_N_ID = @MOT_N_ID 
                and BOO.SCO_N_ID = @SCO_N_ID
        )

    RETURN @BOOK_CODE
    END;
    GO
```

The variable @SCO_N_ID can be a null value however and when it returns a null value SQL interprets the condition as:

> BOO.SCO_N_ID = null

It is not interpreting it as:

> BOO.SCO_N_ID is null

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a column is equal to a variable which can be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741378/how-to-check-if-a-column-is-equal-to-a-variable-which-can-be-null)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WHERE clause using values that could be NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202766/where-clause-using-values-that-could-be-null)

Comment: By the way, you could dispense with all the variables and just do a join `select VEN.VEN_CH_CODE from BOOK BOO join AUTHOR AUT on BOO.MOT_N_ID = @MOT_N_ID and exists (select BOO.SCO_N_ID intersect select AUT.SCO_N_ID) where AUT.AUT_ID = @AUTHOR_ID`.

Comment: Side note, you are likely to get (much) better performance with an inline table value function, rather than a multi-line scalar function here.

Comment: Something seems suspicious here. You assume that (MOT_N_ID, SCO_N_ID) in Book is unique since that query will generate an error if multiple rows are returned. In that same query, "VEN" is not an alias that is defined - that will generate a compilation error. In real life, a book can have multiple authors which is usually implemented as a separate table. But perhaps this is a learning exercise about functions and not db design.

Comment: @Larnu:  An  inline table value function?  Can you explain more please?  I have just started to learn about table value functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this check

"the variable is null or the field is equal to the variable"

```
and (@SCO_N_ID is null or BOO.SCO_N_ID = @SCO_N_ID)
```

Comment: how does this work? there is no comparison on your null check. If the parameter is null then you get all records.

Comment: It depends what is the logic which wasn't really explained in the question.
If it should be an optional param then my answer would be correct. If it should compare then you could use ISNULL() on both sides. So the question is what does the NULL represent

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_BOOK_CODE_BY_AUTHOR_ID] 
(
    @AUTHOR_ID int
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
         @BOOK_CODE varchar(50);

    SELECT TOP 1 @BOOK_CODE = VEN_CH_CODE
    FROM BOOK BOO
    INNER JOIN AUTHOR AUT
        ON AUT.MOT_N_ID = BOO.MOT_N_ID
    WHERE
        BOO.SCO_N_ID = AUT.SCO_N_ID OR
        (BOO.SCO_N_ID IS NULL AND AUT.SCO_N_ID IS NULL)
    ORDER BY BOO.SCO_N_ID, BOO.MOT_N_ID

    RETURN @BOOK_CODE
    END;
```

Note I have joined the tables to make one query, also note I have put a TOP 1 because it might be possible for the query to return more than one result set. If you use TOP 1 then you should have an ORDER BY clause to make sure you return the result you want

Answer (score 1):

**There are a few important points to note here:**

- Firstly, to compare while taking nulls into account, instead of `a = b` you can use this syntax `exists (select a intersect select b)`. This will compile down to an `IS` comparison, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67203618/14868997), and is very efficient
- You can dispense with all the variables and just do a simple join
- User-defined scalar functions are very slow. You will get much better performance from an inline Table-Valued Function

```sql
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_BOOK_CODE_BY_AUTHOR_ID] 
(
    @AUTHOR_ID int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN (
    select VEN.VEN_CH_CODE
    from BOOK BOO
    join AUTHOR AUT on BOO.MOT_N_ID = AUT.MOT_N_ID
      and exists (select BOO.SCO_N_ID
                  intersect
                  select AUT.SCO_N_ID)
    where AUT.AUT_ID = @AUTHOR_ID
);

GO
```

You can use it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM GET_BOOK_CODE_BY_AUTHOR_ID(101) b;
```

Or like this

```
SELECT *
FROM OtherTable t
CROSS APPLY GET_BOOK_CODE_BY_AUTHOR_ID(t.authorId) b;
```

Or this

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT * FROM GET_BOOK_CODE_BY_AUTHOR_ID(t.authorId))
FROM OtherTable t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to set both sides to an unavailable code, I will use -99 in this case.

```
ISNULL(BOO.SCO_N_ID,-99) = ISNULL(@SCO_N_ID,-99)
```